# Opencv c ++ como mostrar um texto (letra) na webcam em c ++?

Tags: c++, opencv

Estou usando, um código aberto, desculpe, sou iniciante, quero mudar isso no `if` e `else`:

```
 else if (!thumbIsOpen && !firstFingerIsOpen && !secondFingerIsOpen && !thirdFingerIsOpen && !fourthFingerIsOpen)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "FIST!";
    }
```

em vez de log, quero mostrar a palavra na webcam como fazer isso em C++?

ou alguma dica de como emendar o Python com C++...

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então descrevendo sucintamente, sem tratar as possibilidades de falha, como frame vazio ou a câmera não ter sido aberta, junto da resposta pra pergunta, temos:

```
// Inicializa a camera
VideoCapture camera;

for(;;)
{

    Mat frame;

    // Passa o frame capturado para a variável
    camera >> frame;

    // Escrevendo em vermelho "Texto na Imagem", no frame a cada novo frame
    cv2.putText(frame, "Texto na Imagem", (0, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255));

    // Exibe a imagem com o texto
    cv2.imshow("Nome da Janela de Exibicao", frame);

    // Para a execução ao pressionar ESC
    if(waitKey(10) == 27)
    {
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Você perguntou como era em C++

Comment: Se quer emendar C com Python, deveria pesquisar por Cython, fora que o código que eu fiz é praticamente o mesmo pra Python, só muda a variável.

Comment: Ok, é que  "cv2.putText" é em python eu acho, tentarei estudar o cython e implementar no projeto, muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento de minha dúvidas!

Comment: putText é da OpenCV, logo serve pra Python e C++

Comment: Entendi desculpe pelo meu erro eu pesquisei e realmente putText serve para ambos, estou somente fazendo errado no código ao executa-lo tenho tipo um erro what is "putText" not declared...

Comment: Verifique os imports

Comment: #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   estou utilizando estes.

Comment: Tenta usar algo pra printar a versão do opencv, pra ver se tá importando mesmo